# Is this a known result on graph products?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, graph-theory, summation

Consider two undirected graphs $G=(V,E)$ and $H=(I,F)$.
Denote by $\mathcal N_G(v)$ (resp., $\mathcal N_{H}(i)$) the first neighborhood of a node $v\in V$ (resp., $i\in I$), including $v$ (resp., $i$).
For each pair of vertices $(v, i)\in V\times I$, take a weight $w(v, i)>0$ and assume that for any $u\in V$, $\sum_{j\in I} w(u, j) \le 1$.

> **Question:** Is there a known (tight!) upper bound of the following quantity? $$Q = \sum_{v\in V}\sum_{i\in I}\frac{w(v,i)}{1-\prod_{u\in\mathcal N_{G}(v)}\left(1-\sum_{j\in\mathcal N_{H}(i)}w(u,j)\right)}$$

---

**My thoughts**

If $F$ is a clique, then
$$Q = \sum_{v\in V}\frac{\sum_{i\in I} w(v,i)}{1-\prod_{u\in\mathcal N_{G}(v)}\left(1-\sum_{j\in I}w(u,j)\right)} \le \frac{\alpha_G + W}{1-e^{-1}}$$
where $\alpha_G$ is the independence number of $G$ and $W = \sum_{v\in V}\sum_{i\in I} w(v,i)$, for a known inequality (see, e.g., [Lemma 3 here](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume20/17-631/17-631.pdf)).

This leads me to believe that a good bound on $Q$ should be a function of three things: 1-2) the independence numbers $\alpha_G$ and $\alpha_H$ of $G$ and $H$ respectively (note that the latter is $1$ in the previous case where $H$ is a clique) and 3) the sum $W$ of all weights.

In particular, this implies that a tight bound should not depend on the cardinalities of $V$ and $I$, because the special case above indicates that if both graphs are well-connected and the weights are small, $Q$ is small no matter how large $V$ and $I$ are.

However, all the inequalities that I can derive easily involve $|V|$ and/or $|I|$, and are therefore loose.

Any even partial answers or ideas that can lead me towards something could be awarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define by $C = G\times H$ the strong product of $G$ and $H$ (kronecker product of $G$ and $H$ with self loops everywhere, then we remove the self loops), with $w((v,i)) = w(v,i)$. Let $\displaystyle  W(v,i) = \sum_{u\in\mathcal{N}_G(v), j\in\mathcal{N}_H(i)}w(u,j)$. As in the original proof, we distinguish the case $W(v,i) \geq 1$ and $W(v,i) < 1$.
The first part of the proof is exactly the same, and we get the bound $\frac{W}{1-e^{-1}}$. The second part is very similar, except we end up on :

$$\frac{1}{1-e^{-1}}\sum_{v\in V, i\in I} \frac{w(v,i)}{W(v,i)} = \frac{1}{1-e^{-1}}\sum_{e\in V(G\times H)} \frac{w(e)}{\sum_{e'\in \mathcal{N}(e)}w(e')} \leq \frac{\alpha_{G\times H}}{1-e^{-1}}$$

We have $\alpha_{G\times H} \leq \rho_G\alpha_H$, where $\rho_G$ is the Rosenfeld number of the graph $G$ (see R.S Hales,
[*Numerical invariants and the strong product of graphs*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895673900142?via%3Dihub), J. Combin. Theory B, 15 (2) (1973), pp. 146-155)